# Is possible to create an android spinner with pull-down like notification bar?

Tags: java, android

for my Android app need a selector that onclick or on pull-down show a dropdown list( not a dialog window), is possible to customize spinner to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you may combine ImageButton with popupWindow than appears just below button ;
popup can have anim and accepts any view hierarchy ;

panels from this demo can be a solution 
http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/